# 4k resolution video encoding in linux

Tags: nvidia, graphics, video, display-resolution

I have a Nvidia GTX 960 GPU and I've used the Nvidia video codec SDK 7.0 to build the `NvEncoder` application and used that to encode from yuv444 to h264, like so:

```
./NvEncoder -i yuv_444_640 -o encoded640.264 -size 640 480 -codec 0 -inputformat 1
```

I have an output file `encoded640.264` that I can play with `ffplay -f h264 encoded640.264` but the video has a green tint and I don't know why.

How do I fix this?